# ftp getting last modified file by date

Tags: bash, ftp

i am connecting remote server via ftp and
i am sending ls -t command but it's outputting files sorted by name

how can i get last modified file via ftp ?

Note: i am connecting windows ftp server from linux machine

Answer (score 5):

`ls -t` will give you the last modified file on top

You can confirm this by viewing with full timestamps

```
ls -lt
```

Comment: @soField, works perfectly. What ftp client are you using? Regular `ftp`?

Comment: we are using windows based ftp server , does it matter ? because when we run ls or ls -t output is same always returns files sorted by name , please see note section i updated question above thanks

Comment: @soField: I've tried from command window - FTP to my server and it works. Can you try the same?

Comment: yeah i tried from windows command line too, same output again , lt ineffective

Comment: This depends on server behavior, not portable, not reliable.

Comment: @JoseK There is no right answer. It depends on the server. If the OP only needs it to work for his server, he can try `ls /od` or `ls -od` (these are DOS `dir` flags) or check the server documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
ftp -n server <<EOF|awk 'END{for(i=9;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s ",$i}'
user username password
ls -ltr
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

In ***most*** Unix/Linux based ftp servers, the `ls` command is linked to the actual `ls` command. This is why all the other answers are saying to use `ls -t` with maybe a few more parameters thrown in.

However, since you're using a Windows machine as your server, it's much harder to say how exactly the command will work. I don't believe Windows comes with a default FTP server service. I know many sites use third party FTP services on their Windows machines. It's going to depend on the software your Windows machine is using, and how it's been setup:

Try something like this:

```
ftp> dir /O:D
```

or

```
ftp> ls /O:D
```

These use the Windows parameters for the built in `dir` command.

Answer (score 2):

try this one, it worked for me.

```
ls -t1 | head -1
```